# Unable to use Ubuntu 19.04 on Asus Vivobook Pro (N580VD)

Tags: boot, nvidia, asus

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 on my Asus Vivobook Pro but I'm unable too.

I've made a bootable USB which works fine (and so does the installation process), But when the installation is finished I'm unable to reboot using the button in the installer (It will freeze). If I'm doing a hard reset, Ubuntu will boot but it will stutter and freeze from time to time.

What I've tried:

- Turned secure boot off
- Turned fast boot off
- Install without Nvidia drivers
- Install with Nvidia drivers
- Use a different bootable USB
- Use a different version (18.04)
- Use a different flavor (Ubuntu Budgie 18.04/19.04)

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer to my problem:

1. Disable secure boot.
2. Load Ubuntu from the USB, select "install Ubuntu" in GRUB and press "e".
3. Change "Quiet splash" to "nomodeset" and press F10.
4. Install Ubuntu with Nvidia drivers.